# hdd boot overrules usb boot option

Tags: boot, grub2

The problem first: When I try to boot Ubuntu from a usb it is somehow overruled by the hdd and boots normally. This happens if I hit f7 to get boot options or if i change the boot priority in the bios.
There is a little hint maybe in the fact that the boot-options screen is seems to be loading twice. (the one that says: f2 for bios f7 for boot options.)

There is a big hint maybe also in the fact that I have recently removed a bunch of (hopefully) old kernel images to free space on my boot partition. On that occasion my Wifi card also stopped working because it "isn't recognized by the system".

It is a custom build laptop that has been running fine until this week where I was told to install windows on it because we need it for drawing autoCAD at uni. Maybe its the bad windows karma that has already caught up with me..

Im really lost here, all I know is that I need windows by monday, hopefully alongside my good old Ubuntu instalation.

Comment: It sounds like your usb stick is not bootable.  Test it in another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the boot USB was not bootable. 
I think it was maybe a problem with the usb image writer that comes with Linux mint. Anyhow I made a new USB-image and it installed like a charm..